# How to speed up the compliation of a large cocoa desktop application in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

In my project there are around 8000 source files and around 1000 xib's in a cocoa desktop application. It takes around 4 minutes to build and launch the application every time if I make any change in a single source file. Is there any way to speed up the build process in xcode?

Comment: Touching one single .m file shouldn't magically rebuild all "`.o`" files.  Is there something about your project that cleans the project before it builds?  Or are you using a way underpowered Mac (e.g. a MacMini)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling for Mavericks, you can take advantage of new technologies like ["`@import`" instead of "`#import`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7), and if you have multiple machines around the office you can use [Xcode's Distributed Build feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917245/when-to-use-the-xcode-distributed-build-feature), which is freaking cool!

Comment: The OP is talking about a Mac program, not an iOS app.

Comment: The question is about OS-X not iOS

Comment: thanks for the -1!  @import also works with compiling for Mavericks.

Comment: I'm a fan of the `@import` feature, so +1.

Comment: @import is quite nice, but from the linked answer I understand it only brings benefits when importing Apple's own frameworks?

Comment: no worries @rmaddy, I kinda deserved that downvote… it was my fault for typing too fast to realize that the o.p. was talking about the MacOS SDK and not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create libraries out of some sections of your code. Then you create a separate Xcode project for each of these libraries.